# Javascript fetch() not returning expected json from localhost

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have a Django backend serving JSON data. When I run `curl 127.0.0.1:8000/posts/` I get:

```json
[
{
"title": "This is a title",
"body": "Body :)",
"pub_date":"2020-11-25T13:36:57Z"
},
...
]
```

However, when I run this js code

```
const API = '127.0.0.1:8000/posts/'
fetch(API).then(response => console.log(response))
```

I get:

```json
Response { 
type: "basic", 
url: "http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:8000/posts/", 
redirected: false, 
status: 200, 
ok: true, 
statusText: "OK",
 headers: Headers, 
body: ReadableStream, 
bodyUsed: false
}
```

which is not expected. If I then attempt to run `.then(response => response.json())` I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

When I run

```
fetch(API).then(response => console.log(response.headers))
fetch(API).then(response => console.log(response.text()))
```

I get

```
Headers {  }
```

```
Promise { "pending "}
   <state>: "pending"
```

respectively

Furthermore,

```
fetch(API).then(response => console.log(response.text()))
fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Just sends back

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

error

Update:

I also noticed on the Django server log that no new requests are appearing when I refresh the javascript page. However, when I run curl there is a GET request.

Comment: Are you running the `response.json()` before your `console.log`? As in: your code should look like this: `fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(response => console.log(response))` not the other way around

Comment: I've tried both. Nothing works!

Comment: Try including `http://` before your IP

Comment: Please post both `response.headers` and `.then(response => response.text())` results to help debug.

Comment: Check the browsers development consoles. If that fetch failed because of CORS or any other issues, it will create an error line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `JSON.parse(response)`;

or

```js
fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {console.log( data })
```

Comment: `response.json()` should parse the json

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: response.json is promise function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the response to be json like below:

```
const API = '127.0.0.1:8000/posts/';
fetch(API)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first if there are any error logs in backend, because if you running frontend and backend on different ports, So, first check if there are not any errors. you might have CORS error.

Then you can try to fetch the data with

```
const API = '127.0.0.1:8000/posts/';
fetch(API)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: I'm not noticing it send a request to the backend at all actually.

Comment: It should, even if you tried it from the console. it will send the request and we will be able to see the backend request. May be the first request is an option request and you are not able to find it.

Comment: I see it on the curl request. Maybe it's an issue with the front end not finding the backend?

Comment: It might be. Add logs on backend endpoint and check if request is racing there or not